# I need to show div over a image when mouse is over it (the image) on large devices, and then, on smaller devices I need them to be next to each other

Tags: html, css

So, if the screen is large (<900px) I need to show multiple images next to each other, and when a user hovers over them, I need a div to appear (it will contain text and one button)

And if the device is medium or smaller (>=900), I need to show that div next to that image. 
It would be awesome if everything can be done with only one div since their content would be the same (div over image and div next to the image on smaller devices)

So far, this is my HTML

```
<div class="col col-6 text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="images/commercial.jpg" alt="" class="image">
            <div class="show_this text-center">
                <div class="text-center image_box" style="">
                    <div class="text-center upper title">Title</div>
                    Text of a div 
                    <div class="contact_button"><a href="conact_us.html">conact 
us</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is a CSS

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.show_this {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background:rgba(225,225,225,0.85);
}

.container:hover .show_this {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This is one solution that works if you hover the mouse, but I was unable to make it so the div is shown next to the image

Comment: Please add code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple @media will help you to solve it:

```
...
.show_this {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background: rgba(225,225,225,0.85);
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .show_this {
    position: static;
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
  }
}
...
```